# Comparing files to each other

Tags: file, file-io, filesystems

I have written some piece of code that copies chunks of big files to a remote machine. Now I would
like to figure out if I really copied all the bits into the right place by comparing those two files
on a byte-per-byte basis. Is there some tool for windows that allows me to do that? I guess Linux
has such a tool already built in, doesn't it?

Many thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

Comparing "byte-per-byte" is probably excessive. That would be equivalent to copying the file again. Build a [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) for each copied portion and compare the checksum value. You can also use the unix command [cksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cksum). You can get the same thing on windows with the [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) package.

Comment: Depends on the intent. For an integrity verifier on important files a hash might not be enough.

Comment: #Vinko, you are technically correct. But applications needing a full bit-by-bit comparison are uncommon. Unless the developer expects the system to be attacked or large amounts of money are involved, i wouldn't think it worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

```
comp
```

Linux:

```
cmp, diff
```

Comment: How long has comp been in windows? I've just tried in my windows 7 box. Thank you!

Comment: `comp` was already included in MS-DOS (and probably other DOS variants as well).

Answer (score 0):

There are tonnes of tools that provide that functionality. Just google for one. I personally use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) which is outstanding. However it costs but there are others such as [windiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff) which are free.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are re-writing

Deltacopy

http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp